# How do you promote a JSON object into an array?

Tags: c#, .net, json

**Is it possible to "promote" a specific part of a json document into an array?**

For example, the input would be something like:

```
{
   "identifier": {"a":"awesome", "b":"back", "c":"cat"}
}
```

suppose I wanted to promote `c`, and in pseudocode, we'd do something like :

```
var payload = "{\"identifier\": {\"a\":\"awesome\", \"b\":\"back\", \"c\":\"cat\"}}";
var payloadWithPromotedC = Promoter.ToArray(payload, "identifier.c");
```

The result would be something like:

```
{
   "identifier": {"a":"awesome", "b":"back", "c":["cat"]}
}
```

**How do we declaritively promote a certain node inside of a json document into an array?**

Comment: Json.NET could do this with a custom converter.

Comment: What do you mean by "declaratively"? Your pseudo-code doesn't look particularly declarative..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "declaratively", but following your example you could do something like this using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
public class Promoter
{
    public static string ToArray(string json, string propertyPath)
    {
        JToken root = JToken.Parse(json);
        JToken tokenToPromote = root.SelectToken(propertyPath);
        if (tokenToPromote == null)
        {
            throw new JsonException(propertyPath + " was not found");
        }
        if (tokenToPromote.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return json;  // value is already an array so return the original JSON
        }
        tokenToPromote.Replace(new JArray(tokenToPromote));
        return root.ToString(Formatting.None);
    }
}
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bOUOWD

Comment: this payload fails: `"{\"identifier\": {\"a\":\"awesome\", \"b\":[{\"back\"}], \"c\":\"cat\"}}"`

Comment: the change i made was putting `back` inside of an object and the object inside of an array: `{\"back\"}`

Comment: Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: }. Path 'identifier.b[0]', line 1, position 43.

Comment: That is because you have made invalid JSON.  You can't have a property name inside an object without a value.  It would have to be `{\"back\":\"something\"}`.  See http://www.json.org/.

Comment: question to you is how do we access structures like these: `{ "yes": [    {"a":"y", "b":"3"}, {"a":"3", "b":"x"}         ] }`

Comment: That sounds like a different question to me-- why don't you post it as a new question describing what you are trying to do.  That way it is more likely you will get a good answer.  Comments aren't a good place to ask new questions because less people will see them, and they are limited by size and formatting.